# Laravel/ajax retrieving data from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I use laravel and now I want to search from DB by ajax. It work but I want to show the result any where that I want not in the footer in current situation.

Do you now how get and show data in this section?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
src = "{{ url('/')}}/users/searchhistory";
 $("#search_text").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: src,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term : request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,

    });
});
</script>
```

And controller

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
    $query = $request->get('term','');

    $products=User::where('fullname','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->get();
    $data=array();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
            $data[]=array('value'=>$product->fullname,'id'=>$product->id);
    }

    if(count($data))
         return $data;
    else
        return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `json()` in return statment of  controller

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request)
{
   //othercodes

   return response()->json($data);
}
```

Then in your ajax result you have the proper json-formatted response 
You can add data to html tag

```
 $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data,function(prodcut){
                // now you have every product 
                use javascript append function to a add new element with this  product data
            });
        }
 });
```

Comment: how I can use it in any html tag?

Comment: @NasserAliKarimi Append the data to html

Comment: @NasserAliKarimi in php you can convert the json string to array 'json_encode' and javascript in 'JSON.parse' function use.

Comment: @NasserAliKarimis because  it's an object! `console.log(product) ` in each statement and then you will see what you got

Comment: In the consol.log I got this(6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
id
:
1
value
:
"ali"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
{value: "hassan", id: 2}
2
:
{value: "alikarimi", id: 4}
3
:
{value: "karimi", id: 5}
4
:
{value: "qasem", id: 7}
5
:
{value: "tagi", id: 8}
length
:
6
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: So ? It's what you wanted

Comment: I want to show id or value seperate from each other any where that I call.

Comment: I try data.id and data['id'] but this two give me "undefined"

Comment: it's a collection of items, plz foreach on it